# Close button not display in Fancybox v2.1.5

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to display a close button on the right side top of a popup. How can i display that? (Fancybox version : 2.1.5)

```html
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="dialogContent">
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fancybox({
       type: 'inline',
        href: '#dialogContent',

    });

    $('div#dialogContent').fancybox();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question? It is not clear - close button is not showing or you want to change its position?

Also, this line - `$('div#dialogContent').fancybox();` makes no sense, because by calling `fancybox()`, you would make your elements clickable (e.g., clicking them would open fancybox).

Comment: fancy box open..but close button not display

Comment: Show your page/demo. Check your page for javascript errors.